# Change root access of a website (PHP)(Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, server, live

I need help as i am new to web development. I have a website which has both "application" folder and a "demo" folder on server. The **APPLICATION** folder contains the codeigniter files which are accessible as i give url: 'www.example.com' and the **DEMO** folder contains the wordpress site which is accessible as 'www.example.com/demo'. now i want to change the access to wordpress when url 'www.example.com' is typed in, i want to load my wordpress site (PLACED IIN DEMO FOLDER). and rest will remain as it is working properly. 
Kindly do tell me what changes need to be changed in order to achieve the mentioned goal. Thanks

Comment: perhaps rename demo to 'applications' and 'applications' to something else for now (but that probably wont be enough). Or change hidden htaccess file (check if it's there) so that it points to your demo folder

Answer (score 1):

This can not be done - You would have both your Codeigniter App and your Wordpress app under http://www.example.com/

I am *guessing* that you want this:

- Have the Wordpress site in your root (http://www.example.com/)

and

- Codeigniter App under subfolder (http://www.example.com/xyz)

If that's the goal, this are the steps:

- **Make a Backup!**
- Create a folder `/xyz`
- Move the following assets to the new folder:

  - `/system` => `/xyz/system`
  - `/application` => `/xyz/application`
  - `/index.php` => `/xyz/index.php`
- Open the `/xyz/index.php` and edit the following lines:

  - `$system_path = 'system';` => `$system_path = '/xyz/system';`
  - `$application_folder = 'application';` => `$application_folder = '/xyz/application';`

As I don't know anything about the Codeigniter App that you have there might be potential issues, such as:

- If your app uses assets (css files, images, js etc) it might have trouble finding them after the move. You will need to edit your View files accordingly. You can probably find them under `/xyz/application/views`
- There is a good chance that you have a hidden file `/.htaccess` which contains configuration to exclude the index.php from your Codeigniter URI Scheme. (Navigate into your codeigniter app and pay attention to the URL while you navigate through the app. Does the URL look like
- (a) `http://www.example.com/index.php/something/else`
- (b) `http://www.example.com/something/else`

If (b) is the case you **will have** to adjust your `.htaccess` file too.

Hope this helps as a starting point....Good luck! :)

Comment: That's exactly what i want, the codeigniter application is complete and is working as required like i can move to different controller "example.com/my_controller/" and it directs me to correct files. Will it be possible after making wordpress site my home page (Mean the main page-www.example.com)

Comment: Yes, but you will have to adjust your `.htaccess` file and create a new `.htaccess` file in the `/xyz` folder. If you have problems with the adjustment of those files I suggest you post a new question (with the current content of those files)

Comment: I dont know much about '.htaccess' file modification. what suitable modifications will be required in order to get everything working again :)

Comment: Ali, I suggest you put the htaccess issue into a new question and post the source code of the `.htaccess` file - that will make it easier to help you. Feel free to ping me with the new question and I am happy to see if I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Use base_url(); to get present url

```
$url = base_url(); // check url.. echo it

if($url == "www.example.com")
{ 
 redirect('www.example.com/demo', 'refresh');
}
```

**

> Add this code at your header on to the top

**

Comment: That's not what the question is asking to do.